# I am comparing a datetime field on two rows of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has several rows of data for a single ID.  I need to compare a datetime field  from a row where a column is = "a" AND grab the datetime and compare it to the same column where the second row is = "b".  IF the time is different I want to report both of these times.

The report is working with the dates but not with the time.

IE  if the dates are the same don't grab the data but of the minutes are different grab the data.

I have created time column but it is not one the table so it is not working.  I am guessing that I need to extract the time from the datetime field as well.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: *"The report is working with the dates but not with the time."* Then show us your SQL; we can't tell you why it isn't working if you don't show us it. Sounds like, however, you just need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value to a `date`.

Comment: Sample data (as `CREATE TABLE/INSERT`) and expected results would help immensely, as would your efforts so far

Comment: Event Table
E-ID |ID|EType|ESubT| DT/TM
4|123|Red|Dark|2/611:45
5|123|Green|ightT|2/613:30
6|234|Red|Light|2/611:45
7|234|Grenn|Dark|2/611:45
8|345|Green|Dark|2/611:45
9|345|Red|Light|2/613:30
10|456|Green|Dark|1/611:45
11|456|Red|Light|2/611:45  
I am expecting a result of  on row for ID 345 and 456 with RED DATE and GREEN DATE populate. The Logic is that if DATETIME DATE portion is same look at TIME  IF LIGHT is after DARK do nothing.    
IF DATES are different Give me both DATEs and TIMES
I hope this helps

Comment: I am rethinking my ? Using datediff.  Alone, this gives me 8 records. I would like to place it as a field to display.  when I add it to the select portion I receive this error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."  Here is the code line.  ( SELECT DATEDIFF(mi ,t1.event_date ,t2.event_date) FROM tb_event t1  INNER JOIN tb_event t2 on t1.incident_id = t2.Incident_id WHERE t1.event_type = 'DISPO'  and t2.event_type = 'SENTPEND'  and t2.event_date between '7/1/2021' and '7/31/2021')

Comment: OK  I have not given up and I am receiving data.  I am now wanting only fields where it is <0  .  I added the row heading TIMEDIFF as a row header and that works.  When I pull the TIMEDIFF into the WHERE clause It is not recognizing the Heading TIMEDIFF.  When I run without the where I receive the column heading TIMEDIFF.  I am a bit confused on what I may have wrong.  Thank you all for your input, questions.  You have guided me very well with your questions for clarifiactions.  Cameron